# remove unconnected nodes R igraph or ggnet

Tags: r, igraph, ggnetwork

I have a symmetric matrix that represent degree of connections among actors.
I would like to cancel out the vertex unconnected.

The functions included in igraph (as delete_edges or delete_vertices) do not work for my case.
I share my code

```
#import of matrix
matrix3<-import("matrix2a.xlsx")
r.name <- matrix2a [,1]
rownames(matrix2a) <- r.name
matrix2a <- matrix2a %>% select(-X__1)
View(matrix2a)
m=as.matrix(matrix2a)
#I compute the maximum spanning tree graph
g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, mode = "upper", weighted = T, diag = F)
max_spann_tree <- mst(g, weights = -E(g)$weight)
#I obtain a network with some unconneted vertex that I would like to erase
```

thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean "The functions included in igraph (as delete_edges or delete_vertices) do not work for my case."  `delete.vertices` is made for 
precisely this purpose.

Since you do not provide data, I will show a small example from random data. I am adding labels to the graph so that the numbering will not change when I delete the isolated vertices.  I am also using an explicit layout so I can lay out the reduced graph in the same way for comparison.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1234)
G = erdos.renyi.game(40, 0.055)
V(G)$label=1:40     
LO = layout_with_fr(G)
plot(G, layout = LO)
```

[image: Graph 01]

Now identify the isolated vertices and use `delete.vertices` to remove them.

```
Isolated = which(degree(G)==0)
G2 = delete.vertices(G, Isolated)
LO2 = LO[-Isolated,]
plot(G2, layout=LO2)
```

[image: Graph 02]

The same graph but without the isolated vertices.

If this is not what you want, please be more explicit about why it does not work for your graph.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  If I refer the function delete.vertices to my "g", that I indicated in my script, I got the answer "Error in delete.vertices(g, Isolated) : delete.vertices requires an argument of class network". How can I cope with this?

Comment: I suspect that you have more than one function `delete.vertices` in your environment.  Please try `igraph::delete.vertices`

Comment: I would think more to a function like this:            "isolated=V(max_spann_tree, which(degree(max_spann_tree)==0) "                But It seems that does not work like this

Comment: I tried also: delete.vertices                                           (max_spann_tree, V(max_spann_tree)[degree(max_spann_tree) == 0])                         without success

Comment: @G5W, Hello, I'm running this code on my igraph object and get the error `(list) object cannot be created to type 'double'`. Can you please help? or simplify the code using `dplyr` and `degree()`

Comment: @Alex  I am not sure what you mean "simplify". It is only a few lines of code. What line of code is giving you that error?

Comment: @G5W, `Isolated = which(degree(G)==0)` its where I get the error. I successfully created the object and need to remove the isolated nodes. I was thinking of something like  `my_igrapgh_object %>% degree() %>% filter` but can't write it

Comment: Sorry,  I am not much of a `dplyr` user.  My way worked for me, but I am not sure what to do with `filter`

Comment: Notice that for a directed graph one needs to use the `mode` parameter in `degree()`, i.e, `degree(G, mode='out')==0`  to remove nodes with 0 outflow connections.