# How to delete vertex with degree = 0 in R (social network data)?

Tags: r, igraph, social-networking, sna, isolate

I want to delete vertices with the code below but have this error message:

> Error in delete.vertices(n_all, V(n_all)[degree(n_all) == 0]) :
> delete.vertices requires an argument of class network.

I follow some suggestions from here ([remove unconnected nodes R igraph or ggnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50679877/remove-unconnected-nodes-r-igraph-or-ggnet)) but still not successful. Any one having solutions would be much appreciated.

```
require(igraph)
meta <- read.csv("vil35_meta.csv", header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
n_all <- graph.adjacency(as.matrix(all), mode = "undirected", weighted = TRUE)
V(n_all)$caste <- meta$castesubcaste
V(n_all)$religion <- meta$hohreligion
V(n_all)$rooms <- meta$room_no

n_all <- delete.vertices(n_all, V(n_all)[degree(n_all)==0])
```

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this problem, so we really need a complete minimal example to proceed.

Comment: Your code works flawlessly on my system (Windows, igraph_1.3.4). Could you please provide the first 10 lines of the csv file? Or as many as needed to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function on the data you are using and pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg